# If a connected planar graph $G$ has $20$ faces, and every vertex of $G$ has degree exactly $4$ then find the number of vertices of $G$.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> A connected planar graph $G$ has $20$ faces, and every vertex of $G$ has degree exactly $4$.
> Find the number of vertices of $G$.

I thought I could probably use the equation that goes like $V+E = F+2$, and I'm pretty sure that the part about each vertex having degree $4$ is a hint on how to find the number of edges, but I'm not sure on how to how to get that.

Answer (score 1):

If every vertex has degree $4$, that means if $V$ is the number of vertices, there are $E = 4V/2 = 2V$ edges.  This is because for a given vertex, we can count $4$ edges incident to that vertex.  But each edge connects exactly $2$ vertices.

The rest is a straightforward application of the equation $V + F = E + 2$.

Comment: Should be instead $|V|+|F|=|E|+2$.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the correction!